# Can't rename packages in Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I want to create some folder structure in `Intellij IDEA` IDE. But, when I am trying to create some folder in other folder, root folder renaming.

For example: There is a folder `src/test/java`. I want to create folder `com/tests`. `com` folder renaming to `com.tests`.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how `IntelliJ IDEA` displays packages a per default.

**To change it:**

In your Project Browser, click the `Settings` Button and deselect `Compact empty Middle Packages`.

**Screenshot:**
[image: IntelliJ compact middle packages]

Comment: where to find it in idea?

Answer (score 2):

To complete jörn-buitink's answer

There's a little gear on top of Project tab. If you press on that gear you will see `Compact Empty Middle Packges` button. That's the one you want to deselect

[image]